# how to mock the service in controller on producer for spring cloud contract

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermockito, spring-cloud-contract

I've been trying to mock the service inside the controller on the producer side

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

    @PostMapping(path = "/getone", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Response> getone(@RequestBody Test[] test) {
    String appId = Utils.getId();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.pub(test,id), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here's how my base test class look like

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ContractTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        mockStatic(Utils.class);
        when(Utils.getId()).thenReturn("194");
       Mockito.when(service.pub(Mockito.any(Test[].class),eq("194"))).thenReturn(TestUtils.publish_success_response());
StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(publishApiController, this.publishService);
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);
    }
```

1. The actual service class runs here instead of the mock which is causing the issue?
   2.How do we test the failure scenarios in the @Before method ?

Comment: `@RunWith` is a JUnit4-annotation, are you sure you're not getting confused by classes from different versions? `SpringExtension` is usually for creating a Spring context, so it would autowire by default, not inject a mock. Try `@MockBean` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an important difference [between @Mock and @MockBean](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/). For your test you need `@MockBean` as you are replacing a Spring bean with a mock for your Spring Test Context.

Apart from this, you are mixing JUnit 4 (`@RunWith`) and JUnit 5 (`@ExtendWith`, `@BeforeEach`).

If you just want to write a test for your controller using `MockMvc`, you don't have to start the whole Spring Context with `@SpringBootTest`. Spring Boot Test provides an annotation to only [start a sliced context](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/) for your MVC components: `@WebMvcTest`.

For the static mock of your `Utils` class, you can use [Mockito (since version 3.4.0)](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/) to reduce the number of additional dependencies and stick to what the Spring Boot Starter Test provides.

A possible test can look like the following:

```
// @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) not needed with recent Spring Boot versions
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest
public class ContractTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Test
    void test() {
      
     try(MockedStatic<Utils> mockedUtils = Mockito.mockStatic(Utils.class)) {
        mockedUtils.when(Utils::getId).thenReturn("194");

        when(service.pub(Mockito.any(Test[].class),eq("194"))).thenReturn(TestUtils.publish_success_response());
        // ... your test
     }
      
    }
}
```